# Django Rest Framework - Get data with Reverse Lookup not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models `book, language, book_language`. when i try to get list of books i am unable to get associated languages with `django_rest_framework`

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.IntegerField()

class Language(models.Model):
    language_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Book_language(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BookLanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book_language
        fields = ('id', 'language',)

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    languages = BookLanguageSerializer(source='language_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'languages')
```

**desired ouput:**

```
 [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'some book 1',
    languages: [
        {
            id: 1,
            language: 'english'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            language: 'chinese'
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    title: 'some book 2',
    languages: [
        {
            id: 1,
            language: 'english'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            language: 'chinese'
        }
    ]
 }]
```

Instead of above output, i am only getting list of books without languages array like below.

```
[{
    id: 1,
    title: 'some book 1',
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    title: 'some book 2',
 }]
```

Also guide where can i find better examples, I tried to read the [DRF doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/?q=ordering) but its not beginner friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `many=True` like

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    languages = BookLanguageSerializer(source='language_set', many=True)
```

Comment: I got this error `Book object has no attribute 'language_set'.` when i use many=True

Comment: There is a basic flaw in your Models. May I know, why haven't you put Language as Foreign Key in Book?

Comment: I guess, a book can have many languages? right? then, in this case, you should use many to many field.

Comment: yes they have ManyToMany relation, i am missing one important thing in `serializers` which i don't know

Comment: ok in this case, you should be using ManyToMany field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: i can not switch to `many_to_many` now, but there is a way to do in DRF since we already have right relationship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156214/discussion-between-mohammad-mustaqeem-and-srinivas).

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    languages = BookLanguageSerializer(source='book_language_set')
```